# Auto naming GraphQL mutation variables based on matching arguments

Tags: variables, graphql, naming, boilerplate, mutation

I wonder if there is any syntactic sugar in graphql mutation that saving me from rewriting the name of the variable? For example, my mutation looks like this (I have to repeat each variable name triple times):

[image: The boilerplate code that I have to write]

I'm expecting something like the javascript's spreading operator, which might looks like this:

```
mutation SaveMedia(...$payload: SaveMediaParams) {
  saveMedia(...$payload) {
    asset {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: not possible, use input type, pass one object

Comment: Ah that will work, why wouldn't I thought about it :)). Thank you very much!

Comment: @xadm I understand that approach, but I prefer explicitly named arguments because of its self-documenting nature. It would be nice to have some syntactic sugar for this, like OP said.